# Regular expression requried in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to extract

`"Memory: (71%)"`   from below mentioned string. This `(71%)` will change every time .

String: `"Memory: 327127123k. total, 2334437k used (71%), 9345624 k free (29%), 1123k buffers"`

So far i have made this Regular expression but it is selecting whole line.

```
{[ regexp { Memory: (.*%)}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? https://regex101.com/r/AQjsFf/1/ Use group 1+2.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to escape the `(` in your regex to make it match on that character, so:

```
{[ regexp { Memory: \(.*%\)}
```

this will match on a string that is similar to

```
"Memory: (71%)"
```

Then you need to account for the characters before and after the percent that you want to capture. There are a couple of ways to do this, including:

1. You could use a group to capture the sub-expression that you are interested in, and allow for extra characters in-between `Memory` and your percentage, so:

   `{[ regexp { Memory:.*(\(.*%\))}`

which is going to find a string with `Memory:` followed by any number of characters ending with `(XXXX5)` where `X` is an undetermined number of characters, so matching things like `(71%)` but also potentially `(ABC%)`.

2. You could encode to the more specific context that you know that you have. Don't use a wildcard character when you know you are looking for digits, so perhaps

   `{[ regexp { Memory:.*\(\d+%\)}`

which is going to only find one or more **digits** followed by `%` in the matching group. If you know that you are going to have two digits, specify that and get even better matches:

```
`{[ regexp { Memory:.*\(\d\d%\)}`
```

or

```
`{[ regexp { Memory:.*\(\d{2}%\)}`
```

both which are looking for two digits only.

Finally, ask why you need to extract `Memory` from the string. Do you need to ensure that the percentage that you match is only from those lines, suggesting other lines in the text also have percentages? OK, you need to match with `Memory`. But if those percentages are only in `Memory` lines, drop that requirement and go with a simple

```
`{[ regexp { \(\d{2}%\) }`
```

which will match any parenthesis containing two digits followed immediately by a `%`,

Comment: A couple of notes: 1) `\D` is **non-digits**, you want `\d` ([ref](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)); 2) `Memory:.*\(\d{2}%\)` will match the **last** percentage on the line because `\*` is greedy. You want `regexp {(Memory:).+?(\(\d+%\))} $line -> label pct; puts "$label $pct"`

Comment: Thanks Shawn but i am little confused here . Just wandering which one would be my final answer .

as in the below mentioned string . I always want to capture " Memory: whatever percentage used is showing only . I want to ignore remaining percentages e.g: free (%)

String : String: "Memory: 327127123k. total, 2334437k used (71%), 9345624 k free (29%), 1123k buffers"


Required from above string :

"Memory: (71%)"

Answer (score 1):

The key with regular expressions is thinking “how can I make this match *just* the part I want?” and writing the RE to work with that case. Here, you want to select the first word up to and including the first colon, skip over everything until the first parenthesis after that, and then match up to and including the next parenthesis. The main trick to remember is that parentheses need backslashes when used as literals because otherwise they are RE metacharacters.

```
set str "Memory: 327127123k. total, 2334437k used (71%), 9345624 k free (29%), 1123k buffers"

if {[regexp {^([^:]*:)[^()]*(\([^()]*\))} $str -> a b]} {
    puts "$a $b"
} else {
    error "didn't match at all"
}
```

Decomposing the RE, there are these pieces:

- `^` — Start of string anchor. Because it is a good idea in general.
- `(` `[^:]` `*` `:` `)` — Capture of everything up to the first colon, i.e., everything that is not a colon and then the colon.
- `[^()]` `*` — Any number of non-parentheses.
- `(` `\(` `[^()]` `*` `\)` `)` — Capture of parentheses round any sequence of non-parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
set s "Memory: 327127123k. total, 2334437k used (71%), 9345624 k free (29%), 1123k buffers"
```

To get `Memory: (71%)`:

```
format {Memory: (%s)} [regexp -inline {\d\d%} $s]
```

Unless the first word in the line changes, this (`\d\d%`) is all you need to match and extract.

You don't actually even need a regular expression, if the number of non-space groups of characters is constant:

```
format {Memory: %s} [string trim [lindex $s 5] ,]
```

Both variants give

```
Memory: (71%)
```

Always avoid regular expression matching if possible.

Documentation:
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)